# Unity CanvasBatchRenderers growing over time

Tags: unity-game-engine, canvas, out-of-memory

I have an application that is meant to stay running for an unlimited time, but it is leaking memory. Profiler shows Other->MemoryPool->CanvasBatchRenderers steadily growing. I have not found any links or documentation relating to this. Looking for tips. ( Unity 5.6.4f1 )

Comment: 1 link found, but not related to my problem https://issuetracker.unity3d.com/issues/memory-leak-if-only-one-display-device-is-connected-when-game-is-using-multiple-displays-and-networking